In Gitlab-CI, how to install packages and keep it to be used in another step like artifacts do?
I'm building a Gitlab-CI flow to deploy a project, bur i need run some NPM scripts in tests and code quality check. There is a way to install the NodeJS in some step and in another step use it?
The point is, i wouldn't like to install the same package again and again for all steps using it.
I have tried something like this, but without success:
stages:
- "Install"
- "Code Quality"

"NPM":
  stage: "Install"
  before_script:
    - curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
    - echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_20.x nodistro main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
    - apt update -y
    - apt install -y nodejs
    - npm install -g npm
    - npm install -g pnpm
    - npm install -g bun
    - npm --version
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run prod
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 days
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - public/

"ESLint":
  stage: "Code Quality"
  dependencies:
    - "NPM"
  before_script:
    - npm --version
  script:
    - npm run eslint

The ESLint step return the following:
/usr/bin/bash: line 159: npm: command not found

Stages are completely separate execution environments. Why not use a Node image to start with?

I'm using another image without Node.

You can use different images in different jobs. But it makes no sense to keep reinstalling NPM each time you run a pipeline or even more in each job.

The solution was use an image with a Node installation.
image: sample/image/with/node/installation

stages:
- "Install"
- "Code Quality"

"NPM":
  stage: "Install"
  before_script:
    - npm --version
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run prod
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 days
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - public/

"ESLint":
  stage: "Code Quality"
  dependencies:
    - "NPM"
  before_script:
    - npm --version
  script:
    - npm run eslint

